# useReducer: Not able to get the initial state using userReducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-reducer, redux-reducers

I have implemented useReducer to dispatch the action based on the action type and each time I'm updating a state variable based on the action type but always I'm getting an error while trying to read the initial state. Probably my code can explain more.

I'm getting the error when I'm trying to read initialLoginState.isLoading.

App.js code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import BottomNavigation from './src/Navigations/BottomNavigation';
import AuthStackNavigation from './src/Navigations/AuthStackNavigation'
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useReducer } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native-animatable';
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { AuthenticationContext } from './src/context/AuthenticationContext'

export default function App() {

  //Initial state values
  const initialLoginState = {
    isLoading: false,
    userName: null,
    userToken: null
  }

//Reducer function
  const loginReducer = (action, prevState) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'LOGIN':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          userName: action.id,
          isLoading: false
        };
      case 'LOGOUT':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userName: null,
          userToken: null,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'REGISTER':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          userName: action.id,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN ':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false
        };
    }
  }

  //Defining useReducer
  const [newLoginState, dispatch] = useReducer(loginReducer, initialLoginState);
  const authContext = useMemo(() => ({
    signIn: (email, password) => {
      // setUserToken('abc');
      // setIsLoading(false);

      console.log("called")
      let userToken
      userToken = null;
      if (email == 'user' && password == 'pass') {
        userToken = 'abc';
      }
      dispatch({ type: 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN', id: email, token: userToken })
    },
    signOut: () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT', })
    },
    signUp: () => {
      setUserToken(null);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }

  }), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let userToken;
    userToken = "dfsdfsdf"
    dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER', token: userToken })
  }, [])

  if (initialLoginState.isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size='large'></ActivityIndicator>
      </View>
    )
  }

  return (
    <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {initialLoginState.userToken !== null ?
          <BottomNavigation />
          :
          <AuthStackNavigation />
        }
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthenticationContext.Provider>

  );
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'newLoginState.isLoading')
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try updating the reducer function to this (flipped the parameters!):

```
//Reducer function
//-  const loginReducer = (action, prevState) => {
  const loginReducer = (prevState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'LOGIN':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          userName: action.id,
          isLoading: false
        };
      case 'LOGOUT':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userName: null,
          userToken: null,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'REGISTER':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          userName: action.id,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN ':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false
        };
      default:
        return prevState;
    }
  }
```

dont forget the default case!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help here. it really did a trick. the worked perfectly fine just by swapping the parameter.

Comment: you are welcome, and the default case don't forget it :)

Comment: Yes, I have added it .

Answer (score 0):

First,  **the default case in the reducer function's switch is missing!**

Second, can you put the whole component code (just the needed part!) because I have no problem running your code even  **without the default case!**

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the complete code for your ref.

Comment: post the component code as whole, not the from here and there so we can see what's going on!

Comment: i have updated my entier App.js file. Please have a look at it.